# Having trouble grasping bivariate probability distributions

Tags: integration, bivariate-distributions, bounds-of-integration

So I'm having trouble grasping bivariate distribution functions. I seem to be struggling with how to determine the upper and lower bounds of my integrals.

So for example, this is a question from my textbook. 
**(I'm really sorry, I'm not very familiar with MathJax and its syntax so this may be a bit messy)**

Let Y1 and Y2 have the joint probability density function given by 
f(y1,y2)= {k(1−y2),    0≤y1≤y2≤1,
                   {0,          elsewhere. 
a Find the value of k that makes this a probability density function. 
b Find P(Y1≤3/4,Y2≥1/2).

I know how to find a double integral, but where I struggle is figuring out what I should be setting my bounds to, and how I should be solving them. I have both a Chegg Study and Slader account, but neither of them really explain their reasoning for selecting their bounds. I feel like I'm on the verge of everything clicking, but I just can't quite get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A probability density function integrates to $1$. The bounds $0\le y_1 \le y_2 \le 1$ mean

$$y_1\le y_2\le 1\\
0\le y_1\le 1$$

so solve the following for $k$

$$\int_0^1\int_{y_1}^1 k(1-y_2)dy_2dy_1=1$$

The part 2 is given by the integral $$\int_{1/2}^1\int_0^{1/2}f(y_1, y_2)dy_1dy_2+\int_{1/2}^{3/4}\int_{y_1}^1 f(y_1, y_2) dy_2dy_1$$

It would be most helpful if you drew a coordinate system of $y_2$ vs $y_1$ and then the identity line $y_1=y_2$. The support will be the area in the unit square above the identity line (a triangle).

[image]

Comment: So solving for K makes a ton more sense now that I've seen it written out like that. But, I'm still a bit lost on the part two. It feels like every solution I've seen uses different bounds but all still get the same answer. I'm not to familiar with what you mean by a coordinate system what a support is (my calculus is few years rusty). I think I'm just trying to understand the reasoning on where why you chose 0≤y1≤1/2 and 0≤y1≤1/2 again? I understand why you are using y1≤y2≤1 and 1/2≤y1≤3/4 on the second I'm just stuck on the first half of part 2.

Comment: It is because the first part is just a square so it will have constant limits of integration. See the attached image (yellow part). The orange part is the second part. We have to split the integral into two parts because of the shape.

Comment: I kind of understand, now. Since Y2≥1/2, the integral will only provide the area above 1/2, and since Y1≤3/4 then it accounts for the area just outside of the square as well. I think the only thing that still confuses me it that on when you integrate from 0 to 1/2 and then 0to1/12, wouldn't that give you the space just below the square and not the square itself? Or do we assume that because everything is less than 1 that integrating from 0 to 1/2 is the same as integrating 1/2 to 1?

Comment: There was an error, we should integrate from 1/2 to 1 for the Y2 :] otherwise it would be below the yellow square. thanks for catching it!

Comment: Not a problem, I should be thanking you. You've been a huge help.